# Can I execute a local program from a Chrome Plugin?

Tags: java, flash, browser, google-chrome-extension, converters

I want to make a Chrome plugin that checks if **mencoder.exe** is present on the clients system. And if so, convert files with it.

Is that possible?

If not, can I make something like that in a Java applet or something? I'm open to suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with java applets, but you also need to implement a permission policy into the program. Here are two tutorials you should take a look at:

Java applets:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

Implementing Policy:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/userperm/policy.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using java applet (like Laerte said), but implementing a policy is not the only option. May be it is easier digital signing ([info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/rsa_signing.html)) your applet with respective attributes in Manifest.mf ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/secman.html)) and wrapping your SO access source lines with [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/doprivileged.html). In this way, you can distribute your applet without modifying client systems.