# chrome/chromium extension: run a executable/script via the context menu

Tags: google-chrome, command, executable, chromium

I'm writing a small chrome extension for personal use and I would like to run an executable via the context menu and pass certain information as arguments to said executable.

What the **simplest** and/or **cleanest** way to achieve this? To me it seems that it is impossible due to chrome's sandboxing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be accomplished [via NPAPI Plugins](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html).

> Code running in an NPAPI plugin has the full permissions of the
>   current user and is not sandboxed or shielded from malicious input by
>   Google Chrome in any way. You should be especially cautious when
>   processing input from untrusted sources, such as when working with
>   content scripts or XMLHttpRequest.

However, I should also include their warning.

> ### Warning
>
> [NPAPI is being phased out.](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html) Consider using alternatives.
>
> NPAPI is a really big hammer that should only be used when no other
>   approach will work.

via [Start an external application from a Google Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652094/start-an-external-application-from-a-google-chrome-extension)

**Alternatives to NPAPI**

1. > There are several alternatives to NPAPI. In cases where standard web
   >   technologies are not yet sufficient, developers and administrators can
   >   use [NaCl](https://developers.google.com/native-client/), [Apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/), [Native Messaging API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging), and [Legacy Browser Support](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3019558?hl=en) to
   >   transition from NPAPI. Moving forward, our goal is to evolve the
   >   standards-based web platform to cover the use cases once served by
   >   NPAPI.

   via http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html
2. Another way, [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19136914/1085891), is with Java.

   > Java applets: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/
   >
   > Implementing Policy: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/userperm/policy.html
3. Use `sendNativeMessage`:

   > There is [chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendNativeMessage) which can be used to send a
   >   message to a native application and [chrome.runtime.connectNative](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-connectNative) which
   >   allows for a more persistent connection.
   >
   > So, you can't directly execute a command, but you can have a native
   >   app do it for you.
   >
   > You can find more info on [Native Messaging in the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging).

   via https://stackoverflow.com/a/19917672/1085891

Comment: So since NPAPI is being phased out, which one of the alternatives should I use? I just want to execute an external program/script, so Apps, Native Messaging API and Legacy Browser Support don't seem to be an option.

Comment: I'm gonna test example given in their page via "Native Messaging" https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging

Comment: Native Messaging seems like the key to getting ZPL and Generic Text-Only printing to work at full speed without prerendering. Albeit, in a chrome only way.

Comment: @JSuar, Isn't **PPAPI** the replacement for NPAPI?

Comment: @Pacerier, yes, I think you're right. I don't know enough and couldn't locate info on PPAPI capabilities as it relates to the original question.