# Disable Predictive Scrolling - Mousewheel (OnScroll) Event fires too often (Touchpad)

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, jquery-events, mousewheel

I am executing Javascript `onScroll`.
My code works great with any normal computer mouse, but when I use my notebook's touchpad, I encounter the following situation:

- my mouse fires (about 1 to 8) `mousewheel` events while the finger is moving the wheel.
- my touchpad fires a lot more (~60) `mousewheel` events while the two fingers are touching the pad **and continues to fire after my fingers are up in the air again.**

I know this behavior from mobile touch devices. The Feature is called "Predictive Touch" - The Scrolling continues if your finger movement had enough acceleration before lifting it up.

I think the touchpad drivers are setting this "smooth scrolling" behavior.

To debug this case, I have used the following code:

```
/* Handle Mouse-Wheel Scrolling */
var lastChange = +new Date();
$(window).bind('mousewheel',    function(e){
    console.log("mw");
    if(+new Date() - lastChange > 1000){
        console.log("mw allowed");
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0)  {/*go to previous*/}
        else{   /*go to next*/}
        lastChange = +new Date();
    }
return false;});
```

This is a simple code that "allows" a mouse-scrolling-event every second.

If I make a fast touchpad-scroll, the `mousewheel` event is fired ~300 times. The one-second-condition is letting 3 events happen. My fingers were on the touchpad for far less than a second.

With this test, I discovered that the `mousewheel` events are still fired (almost continuously for 3 seconds), even when my fingers are already off the touchpad.

Is there a Javascript function or a workaround / trick / hack to avoid this behavior?

**Something like a `onTouchEnd` event for touchpads, maybe?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you'd have to distinguish between mouse scroll events and touchpad events, which is not (yet) possible using JavaScript. It was already asked in question [How to capture touch pad input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448257/how-to-capture-touch-pad-input).

[Pointer Events](https://w3c.github.io/pointerevents/) are currently in state of Editor's Draft and not yet supported by any browser. See also [touch events docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events).

Comment: It wouldn't be enough to just distinguish between touchpad events and wheel events, would it? You'd still need a way to determine if an event was triggered by inertial scrolling, and that will probably require touchpads to start triggering the `touchstart` and `touchend` events. Or am I not thinking this through?

Comment: @DoctorDestructo Yes, you're right. I assume that Pointer Events will provide  `touchstart` and `touchend` events for touchpads.

Comment: two years later, we now got a level 2 editor's draft, it's a shame it's developing that slowly, but i appreciate that there is a progress at all :) https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents2/

Comment: three years later, we now have a level 3 editor's draft. Guys, we are almost there! https://w3c.github.io/pointerevents/ - already with full browser support or polyfill in all major browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer . I might test soon if my issue can be resolved using this API.

Comment: @GlabbichRulz Unfortunately and as is this won't help as touchpad events are still emitted as mouse events by the browsers/OS (don't know which one is to blame here)...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This doesn't appear to work for trackpads. Once they are widely supported, this could be implemented using [Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events), specifically the [Touch End](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend) event. By tracking when the finger leaves the trackpad, you can prevent the page scrolling at that particular point.

https://jsfiddle.net/gLkkb5z0/3/

```
(function(){

    var special = jQuery.event.special,
        uid1 = 'D' + (+new Date()),
        uid2 = 'D' + (+new Date() + 1);

    special.scrollstart = {
        setup: function() {

            var timer,
                handler =  function(evt) {

                    var _self = this,
                        _args = arguments;

                    if (timer) {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                    } else {
                        evt.type = 'scrollstart';
                        jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self, _args);
                    }

                    timer = setTimeout( function(){
                        timer = null;
                    }, special.scrollstop.latency);

                };

            jQuery(this).bind('scroll', handler).data(uid1, handler);

        },
        teardown: function(){
            jQuery(this).unbind( 'scroll', jQuery(this).data(uid1) );
        }
    };

    special.scrollstop = {
        latency: 300,
        setup: function() {

            var timer,
                    handler = function(evt) {

                    var _self = this,
                        _args = arguments;

                    if (timer) {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                    }

                    timer = setTimeout( function(){

                        timer = null;
                        evt.type = 'scrollstop';
                        jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self, _args);

                    }, special.scrollstop.latency);

                };

            jQuery(this).bind('scroll', handler).data(uid2, handler);

        },
        teardown: function() {
            jQuery(this).unbind( 'scroll', jQuery(this).data(uid2) );
        }
    };

})();
```

[Demo](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/scrollevents/)

Taken from http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. Reading the article, i thought this is exactly what i need. But I tried the demo on my Laptop and the "scrolling" status is still active for like 3 to 4 seconds after my fingers are off the touchpad. It does not work for me, do you have another idea?

Comment: Possibly using [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events), specifically the [touchend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend) event.

Comment: Hello, i have tested the touch events API using a touchscreen laptop. The touchscreen is detected and works as intended. The touchpad however has it's default scrolling behaviour and there are no events recorded. I also tried different mousewheel & scrolling events [in this demo](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/scroll.html), but it did not help as well. Do you have another idea?

Comment: @Gothdo reading the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events), touch events should be able to support trackpads in the future: "_touch events offer the ability to interpret finger (or stylus) activity on touch screens or trackpads._"

Comment: Looks as if touchpads aren't currently supported in most cases, however it looks like you may be able to achieve what you want in the future using those events, with any luck. On the negative side, we have no idea when these events will be supported by browsers for trackpads. It also looks as if this feature is [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events#Browser_compatibility) in firefox due to issues with some sites. I'll add this to the answer for anyone searching this in the future.

Comment: I've also added a jsfiddle that should work when these events are fully supported. My scroll stopping code doesn't feel right however.

Comment: Thank your for the effort you put into answering this question. The jsfiddle didn't work like this due to some wrong code but [i fixed it](https://jsfiddle.net/gLkkb5z0/3/) and played around a bit. It is interesting that if i tell the browser to scroll to top on touchend, it does scroll to top if my (touchscreen-) finger lifts off with no remaining acceleration, but if lift it up "in the move", the event is triggered but the scroll to top never happens, the div actually continues to scroll down. I'm curious how this can be handled in the future

Comment: Great! Thanks for fixing that code. Do you mind if I add it to the answer? I'd rather having a working demo for future readers to see than a semi working one.