# Detecting when finger is removed from touchpad but scroll is still happening due to "predictive touch" - JS

Tags: javascript

I have a function that handles scrolls every period of time. This function works when users scroll with mouse wheel:

```
let shouldHandle = true
window.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
    if (shouldHandle) {
        handleScroll(e) // I will handle scrolls here
        shouldHandle = false
        setTimeout(() => {
            shouldHandle = true
        }, 750)
    }
})
```

However, when I am scrolling using my laptop's touchpad, scroll still happens even when I remove my finger (especially when I accelerate my finger enough and scroll, then immediately remove my finger from the touchpad). As a result, scroll still happens after the `750ms` even when the users are not technically scrolling. This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831120/disable-predictive-scrolling-mousewheel-onscroll-event-fires-too-often-touc). The question did not receive an answer to handle this behavior.

I want to handle scroll only after a period of time has elapsed from the last scroll. The scrolls I want to handle must not be because of scrolling caused by this "predictive touch" scroll. Is there a way to achieve this as of now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to handle that that comes to mind is to watch `scrollY` for a period of time (polling, perhaps every 50ms or so) after you've seen a scroll start and wait for it to stabilize (X milliseconds in the same position, for whatever value of X you decide on) and only then consider that scroll "completed" and start your 750ms timer. Constantly polling would be bad, but doing it for a brief period while the scrolling is still actively occurring seems acceptable.

Rough sketch (could probably use an overall timeout, for instance):

```
// VERY ROUGHLY
let shouldHandle = true
let lastScrollY = null
let lastScrollTimer = 0
window.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
    if (shouldHandle) {
        handleScroll(e) // I will handle scrolls here
        shouldHandle = false
        waitForScrollEnd(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                shouldHandle = true
            }, 750) // Or perhaps 700 on the basis that up to 50 was spent in `waitForScrollToEnd`
        })
    }
})
function waitForScrollEnd(cb) {
    clearTimeout(lastScrollTimer)
    lastScrollY = window.scrollY
    lastScrollTimer = setTimeout(poll, 50)

    function poll() {
        if (lastScrollY === window.scrollY) {
            lastScrollY = null
            lastScrollTimer = 0 // This is entirely optional but makes it parallel with the `else` below
            cb()
        } else {
            lastScrollY = window.scrollY
            lastScrollTimer = setTimeout(poll, 50)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that the code should have this line inserted before the last fourth line: `lastScrollY = window.scrollY`. Also, this code means that continuous scrolling not caused by "predictive touch" (instead because the user is really scrolling) not to be handled, right?

Comment: @Richard - I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by "the last fourth line. I'm fairly sure `lastScrollY = window.scrollY` isn't needed anywhere it isn't already in the above. Yes, `waitForScrollEnd` will wait for scrolling to end regardless of why it's ongoing.

Comment: @Richard - (I don't think this relates to your comment.) Looking at the above with fresh eyes, it seems to me it wants to cancel a previous `waitForScrollEnd` if a new event comes in. I've added that, but it was really just a tweak anyway...

Comment: Ah what I meant was: your code before only calls `waitForScrollEnd` once, which is when the user first scrolls. Afterwards, `waitForScrollEnd` will only update `lastScrollY` once, but calls `poll` every 50ms. However, as `lastScrollY` is only updated once, `poll` will continuously be called every 50ms even when the scroll has stopped.

Comment: @Richard - Doh!! Fixed. :-) (Fourth from last, I get it now.)

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry, I meant `fourth from last` or `fourth to last`. Thank you for the answer.